# How to prevent user multi-select in Excel pivot tables?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, multi-select, slicers

I have an Excel pivot table that is date based.  I want to force users to 1 and only 1 year plus 1 and only 1 quarter for their reporting.  Is there anyway to do this in filters or slicers or should I brute force it in VBA.  I'm very comfortable with VBA in Access and Word, but haven't had much call to VBA in Excel.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possible approaches. First, here's some code from [Jerry Sullivan over at the MrExcel forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/675168-limiting-slicer-multiple-selection-2.html#post4595304) that does this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
'--when pivot update event triggered, checks whether a specified slicer
'    has more than one item selected.
'  If so, user is warned and optionally the last action can be undone.

 Dim bSlicerIsConnected As Boolean
 Dim pvt As PivotTable
 Dim slc As SlicerCache
 Dim sLastUndoStackItem  As String

 '--modify this to match your slicer's name
 Const sSLICER_NAME As String = "Slicer_Name3"

 sLastUndoStackItem = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)

 '--validate event was triggered by slicer or filter, not other pivot operation
 Select Case sLastUndoStackItem
   Case "Slicer Operation", "Filter"
      'continue
   Case Else
      'do nothing and exit
      GoTo ExitProc
 End Select

 '--validate specified slicer exists
 On Error Resume Next
 Set slc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(sSLICER_NAME)
 On Error GoTo 0

 If slc Is Nothing Then
   GoTo ExitProc
 End If

 '--validate pvt that triggered event is connected to specified slicer
 For Each pvt In slc.PivotTables
   If pvt.Name = Target.Name Then
      bSlicerIsConnected = True
      Exit For
   End If
 Next pvt

 '--test how many items selected and take action if more than one
 If bSlicerIsConnected Then
   If slc.VisibleSlicerItems.Count > 1 Then
      '--option a: only warn user
      'MsgBox "Only one item may be selected" & vbCr _
      '  & "Please undo last selection."

      '--option b: warn user and undo
     ' MsgBox "Only one item may be selected"
      With Application
         .EnableEvents = False
         .Undo
      End With
   End If
 End If
ExitProc:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you didn't want VBA, then you could use s[omething like i posted here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/), by creating a second PivotTable, putting the field of interest in it as a Report Filter i.e. Page Field, and then effectively 'dress up' the two resulting cells as a kind of Data Validation Dropdown. You would need to use formulas to check that only one item was selected (i.e. by checking that the dropdown doesn't say "(All)".